# Using NHibernate, how can I save all my repositories in a single Save()

Tags: nhibernate, orm, frameworks, repository, entity

I'm using the Repository/Unit of Work pattern in a project using NHibernate. I have a number of repositories, such as Customer and Account. Each repository is associated with the same ISession (unit of work pattern) by passing in the same ISession object to the constructor of each repository.

I then create a bunch of customers and their associated accounts and add them to their respective repositories. Now I want to save these repositories to the database. However, to save in NHibernate involves calling ISession.Save() and passing in an entity. If I was using the Entity Framework instead, and my ISession was an ObjectContext, I would be able to call ObjectContext.SaveChanges() and the contents of all my repositories would be saved to the database.

How can I do this in NHibernate? It seems odd that I have to save each object individually, rather than the ISession as a whole. I also have to save them in a specific order, since a Customer must have an account (AccountID FK in customer table cannot be null) I must therefore save the account first, followed by the customer.

What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the part where you associate a new object with the ISession (session.Save()). Otherwise how does NH know that some object you created needs to be persisted? If you are only modify existing objects (that you've fetched from the ISession) then all you need to do is commit the transaction/flush the session.

For the customer -> account relationship, you could make the customer cascade saves on it's account.

Comment: "associate a new object with the ISession" - Is this not done when I pass the ISession to the constructor of my repository? So the repository is associated with the ISession, and the object is part of the repository. When I Flush() the repositories should be save then?

Comment: Yes, if you fetch an existing object from the session, then it will be tracked by that session. I'm talking about saving a new object (inserting) to the database. The only way to insert a new object is by calling Save() in some way, either on the object or indirectly through cascades.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow you. If calling Save() on each individual object is the only way to persist a new object to the database, then this leaves me back at my original problem. I have to call Save() on every new object. I want to just call Flush() on the entire session after I've populated all my repositories with objects. Calling Save() on every new object is an awful lot of method calls. What do you mean by "fetch an existing object from the session"? Do you mean "fetch an existing object from the database?"

Comment: If you're using repository pattern then you probably have an `Add()` method which would call `session.Save(entity)`? How else would you implement a repository with the ISession??

Comment: I have an ICollection object inside my repository. Within the Add() method I just add the entity to this collection (I've used the ICollection as a substitute for an Entity Framework IObjectSet). I guess I'm not doing this correctly, and I should be calling Save() on the isession here. That probably explains where Im going wrong. If this were the Entity Framework my Add() method in the repository would just add to the IObjectSet.

Comment: Oh, ISession does all that for you out of the box. Repository with ISession is more of wrapper around the ISession interface.  Remove that `_objectSet` field  and change your Add method to `public void Add(T entity) { _isession.ThisSession.Save(entity); }` and it will be inserted when you flush that session.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Will change my method later and test it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to save your objects explicitly. Hibernate has been built with so called "Persistence Ignorance" in mind. Just flush the session and all changes to all known entitys will be persisted.

So just call `Session.Flush();`

Comment: Does this handle inserts of top-level items?

Comment: No, a newly created top-level entity is unknown to the session and needs to be registered with a call to Save();